# Can this coDrops link effect work on text in <span> element?

Tags: css, animation, hover, html, pseudo-element

I am trying to emulate the CSS animation from here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/06/creative-link-effects/ on words in a paragraph text. And am having absolutely no success. I'm wondering if  doesn't support pseudo elements or they way I've used them is wrong. I have definitely tested and confirmed that  elements support hover. And I have also seen some examples of CSS animation on text upon hover. But I cannot seem to get my example to work.

Here is the code on codepen http://cdpn.io/bjGxl

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your css

```
.highlight:hover::before,
.highlight:focus::before,{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

should be

```
.highlight:hover::before,
.highlight:focus::before{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

.highlight:focus could be removed, since a span can't have focus.

http://cdpn.io/uEiKf